# Mulesoft transform message escaping forward slash

Tags: java, mongodb, mule, dataweave

Within transform message, I am trying to write a MongoDB query. The query requires forward slashes like such:

```
{Event: { $in: [ /NOVEMBER/, /OUTDOORS/]}}
```

I am currently writing this in transform message:

```
{
    Event: {'\$in':
        [
          / flowVars.Month / ,
          / flowVars.LocationType /
        ]
    }
}
```

and am receiving the errors: 
    no viable alternative at input '/'
    no viable alternative at input ','

Does anyone know how to resolve these issues?

Answer (score 2):

Do you just want simple string concatenation, using `++`? 
Credit to @jerney below for pointing out redundant code from my previous answer.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json

%function wrap(s) "/" ++ s ++ "/"
---
Event: {
    "\$in": [
        wrap(flowVars.Month),
        wrap(flowVars.LocationType)
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could also create a function `%function wrap(s) "/" ++ s ++ "/" ` and use that in case you're going to be using that logic a lot.

Comment: This particular function still is not accomplishing what I would like. Mule is giving me the following error: 
org.mule.api.MessagingException: Failed to transform from "com.mulesoft.weave.mule.WeaveMessageProcessor$WeaveOutputHandler" to "org.bson.Document" (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException). Message payload is of type: WeaveMessageProcessor$WeaveOutputHandler

Comment: That's an entirely different issue. If this answer is generating the correct structure for your payload (which is answering your question) and getting you passed the error you were having, you should mark it as accepted. If you open up another question regarding your WeaveOutputHandler -> org.bson.Document issue, I'm sure someone would be willing to help.